# Can we express the following in a closed form?

Tags: integration, analysis, closed-form

I want to evaluate the integral: 
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln \left ( \frac{(1+\sin x)^{1+\cos x}}{1+\cos x} \right )\,dx$$

Well, the sub $u=\pi/2-x$ does not give me any result. In fact it makes the integral more complicated that it actually is, unless I do not see something.

The method above is the only one I used since I do not see something else in this point.
Any help would be grateful.

Comment: Not a very nice one. [The antiderivative brought to you by wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+ln%28%28%281%2B+sin+x%29^%281%2Bcos+x%29%29%2F%281%2Bcos+x%29%29)

Comment: Mathematica returns the simple result of $\ln 4-1$ for this definite integral (though Wolfram Alpha sadly only gives the numerical result). So there's an endpoint. That said, how to get there isn't immediately obvious to me.

Comment: @recursiverecursion Apparently the antiderivative is not elementary... , but something tells me that the definite integral can be evaluated elementary..

Comment: @Semiclassical What is the result that mathematica returns?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idea in the following is to simplify using logarithmic identities, and then to get rid of the nasty integration term using the symmetry of the limits.
$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_{0}^{\Large\frac\pi2}\ln \left ( \frac{(1+\sin x)^{1+\cos x}}{1+\cos x} \right )\,dx
\\&=\int_{0}^{\Large\frac\pi2}[(1+\cos x)\ln(1+\sin x)-\ln({1+\cos x})]\,dx
\\&=\int_{0}^{\Large\frac\pi2}[\cos x\ln (1+\sin x)+\ln(1+\sin x)-\ln({1+\cos x})]\,dx
\\&=\int_{0}^{\Large\frac\pi2}\cos x\ln (1+\sin x)\,dx+\int_{0}^{\Large\frac\pi2}[\ln(1+\sin x)-\ln({1+\cos x})]\,dx
\\&=\int_{0}^{\Large\frac\pi2}\cos x\ln (1+\sin x)\,dx
\end{align}$$
in which the second term vanished because 
$$\int_{0}^{\Large\frac\pi2}\ln(1+\sin x)\,dx=\int_{0}^{\Large\frac\pi2}\ln(1+\cos x)\,dx$$

Now performing the substitution $u=1+\sin x$, we get

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_{0}^{\Large\frac\pi2}\cos x\ln (1+\sin x)\,dx
\\&=\int_{1}^{2}\ln u\,du
\\&=\bigg[u\ln u-u\bigg]_1^2
\\&=2\ln2-1.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Nicely done. +1

Comment: Thank you... ! I guess I had to go around a little more with this.. so that I applied logarithmic properties... which kill the integral... Anyway , nice solution

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Thanks for the edit